# Asynchronously traverse a task tree

Tags: javascript

For a tree of tasks, something like this:

```
var taskTree = {
  a: task_a,
  b: ()=> {
    'b1': task_b1,
    'b2': task_b2
  }),
  c: task_c,
  d: task_d
};
```

How to traverse a tree of tasks asyncronously so that parent nodes get executed first and after that execute child nodes asyncronously? I'm something expecting this:

```
Starting task with id: 1
Starting task with id: 2
Starting task with id: 3
Starting task with id: 4
Finishing task with id: 1
Finishing task with id: 2
Finishing task with id: 3
Finishing task with id: 4
Starting task with id: 11
Starting task with id: 22
Starting task with id: 33
...
```

I tried to figure how to execute tasks asyncronously like I need, but even that is not giving expected results.

```js
async function promise(id) {
    console.log(`Starting task with id: ${id}`);
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(async () => {
            console.log(`Finishing task with id: ${id}`);
            resolve(true);
            if(id == 1) { await Promise.all([promise(11), promise(111), promise(1111)]); }
            if(id == 2) { await Promise.all([promise(22), promise(222), promise(2222)]); }
            if(id == 3) { await Promise.all([promise(33), promise(333), promise(3333)]); }
            if(id == 4) { await Promise.all([promise(44), promise(444), promise(4444)]); }
        }, 100);
    });
}

async function test() {
    const p1 = promise(1);
    const p2 = promise(2);
    const p3 = promise(3);
    const p4 = promise(4);
    const result = await Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, p4]);
}
test()
```

Comment: Instead of using an `async` callback for `setTimeout`, it'd probably be better to write a promise-returning `timeout` function, and then call and `await` that wherever you need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically,

```js
async function exec(task) {
    await task.fn()
    await Promise.all(task.subs.map(exec))
}

//

let work = (s) => new Promise(r =>
    setTimeout(() => r(console.log('done', s))))

tasks = [
    {
        fn: () => work(1),
        subs: [
            {
                fn: () => work(11),
                subs: []
            },
            {
                fn: () => work(12),
                subs: [
                    {
                        fn: () => work(121),
                        subs: [
                            {
                                fn: () => work(1211),
                                subs: [],
                            },
                            {
                                fn: () => work(1212),
                                subs: [],
                            }

                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    {
        fn: () => work(2),
        subs: [],
    }
]


async function test() {
    await Promise.all(tasks.map(exec));
}
test()
```

Comment: Not sure why this answer was accepted. The question shows that the parent task execution should complete before the child execution should happen. However, this answer doesn't do that?

Comment: @vincent: what makes you think so?

Comment: Plug the "work" function from my answer into yours and take a look at the difference in output

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using [object-scan](https://github.com/blackflux/object-scan). First we determine the tasks that should be executed in parallel, then we execute them.

```js
// const objectScan = require('object-scan');

const tasks = (() => {
  const work = (s) => new Promise((resolve) => {
    console.log('start', s);
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('done', s);
      resolve();
    }, 10);
  });
  return [
    {
      fn: () => work(1),
      subs: [
        {
          fn: () => work(11),
          subs: [
            {
              fn: () => work(111),
              subs: []
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          fn: () => work(12),
          subs: [
            {
              fn: () => work(121),
              subs: [
                {
                  fn: () => work(1211),
                  subs: []
                },
                {
                  fn: () => work(1212),
                  subs: []
                }

              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      fn: () => work(2),
      subs: [
        {
          fn: () => work(21),
          subs: []
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
})();

const extractor = objectScan(['**(^subs$).fn'], {
  useArraySelector: false,
  filterFn: ({ depth, value, context }) => {
    while (context.length <= depth) {
      context.push([]);
    }
    context[depth].push(value);
  }
});

(async () => {
  const fns = extractor(tasks, []);
  for (let idx = 0; idx < fns.length; idx += 1) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-await-in-loop
    await Promise.all(fns[idx].reverse().map((fn) => fn()));
  }
})();
// => start 1
// => start 2
// => done 1
// => done 2
// => start 11
// => start 12
// => start 21
// => done 11
// => done 12
// => done 21
// => start 111
// => start 121
// => done 111
// => done 121
// => start 1211
// => start 1212
// => done 1211
// => done 1212
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script src="https://bundle.run/object-scan@14.2.0"></script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)